# How do you animate a lock screen widget on iOS 16?

Tags: ios, swiftui, widgetkit, swiftui-animation, swiftui-image

In iOS 16, Lock screen widgets allow you to add an Image to the `WidgetView`, like in `accessoryCircular`.

How do you animate this Image? Loading the Image from an animated UIImage with frames just displays the first frame.

Am I missing a `startAnimating` call, like you have to do with `WKInterfaceObject`s? Is there some additional step or value to set to get an Image inside a SwiftUI `WidgetView` to begin animating, or cycling through frames?

Examples of apps that have achieved this are https://www.livelywidget.com or Pixel Pal, so I know it's possible, but when I search for APIs to accomplish this, all that comes up are apps.

Comment: Hello Erika, did you manage to find some information about this matter?